# Unable to set the representation option of the "to" (range-phrase) while using SIrange within a chemformula (chemmacros) command

Tags: siunitx, chemmacros, chemformula, sirange

EDIT (supplement): the behaviour is the same within all use-cases (environment as well as `\ch` command)  provided by the chemmacros package.

In a chemmacros `reactions` environment I tried to switch from the "to" or in German "bis" to just a "`--`" for the `\SIrange`-given temperature range on top of a reaction arrow.

with loaded

```
\usepackage{chemmacros}
                 % includes \usepackage{chemformula}
\usechemmodule{all}
                
\chemsetup{
                %
    language=auto,
                %
    charges/circled = all,
                %
    redox/parse = false,
                %
    redox/pos = top,
                %
    formula=chemformula
                %
}
```

I tried

```
\begin{reactions}
        A &->[\SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}] C+ 3 C ^ \\
    2 D + C &->[\SIrange[range-units=single,range-phrase = -- ]{200}{300}{\degreeCelsius}] 2 E ^ + F
\end{reactions}
```

and get a bunch of errors. The first one is "`Package siunitx Error: Unknown option 'range-phrase\tl_use:N`" without a line-number, followed by "`Package siunitx Error: Invalid token '\chemformula ' in numerical input. \end`"  and "`Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '\chemformula_subscript:n(siunitx) {0}\chemformula_subscript:n {0}'. \end`" referring the line of "`\end{reactions}`". The following are mostly referring to missing or to much "`}`".

So I tried with the same result

```
\begin{reactions}
    \sisetup{
        range-units=single,
        range-phrase = -- , 
    } %
    A &->[\SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}] C+ 3 C ^ \\
    2 D + C &->[\SIrange{200}{300}{\degreeCelsius}] 2 E ^ + F
\end{reactions}
```

Without the

```
range-phrase = -- ,
```

option statement everything runs smoothly, in both cases.

Maybe it's only a typo ? But `range-phrase` is looked up with the manual of siunitx. Hence I'm wondering on the first errors statement ("`Unknown option 'range-phrase`")

EDIT (supplement): Tried in `equation` – and `eqnarray` – environment: same situation.

The environment used is the actual MikTex.

Any ideas how to set that range-phrase option ?

EDIT (supplement): Liked to an issue on [chemmacros github](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/33).

Comment: Did you already try using the `\sisetup` outside of the `reactions` environment? `{
    \sisetup{
        range-units=single,
        range-phrase = {--} , 
    } %
\begin{reactions}
    A &->[\SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}] C+ 3 C ^ \\
    2 D + C &->[\SIrange{200}{300}{\degreeCelsius}] 2 E ^ + F
\end{reactions}
}`

Comment: No, I didn't. Tried now. That has results like expected. But then the change is active outside the environment as well... So I would have to set it back to default after the environment, but what is default, that way that it is respects the language settings? And why is range-units=single working inside properly ?

Comment: If you surround the sisetup and the corresponding reactions command with a set of {} as I did in my comment, the sisetup is local to the part in {}, so no need to reset it later.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis. Good idea. Could have come up with it myself ;-).

Comment: (Almost) every input inside of a `reaction` environment behaves as if it was input directly into `\ch{}`.

Comment: As you see, I changed the info. The issue is the same in all use-cases. But what is the difference between option `range-units` and `range-phrase` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see, where the problem is. Almost everything inside a `reactions` environment acts the same as if it were put directly into `chemformula`'s `\ch`. (Almost because things like `&` or `\\` need to work differently here…). Now let's look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\ch{A -- B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems surprising unless you think about it: `chemformula` splits this into three pieces: `A`, `--`, and `B`. None of these match special input so they're all treated as compounds. Inside a compound `-` is replaced with a single bond unless it is superscripted. A trailing `-` is treated as if it were superscripted. This is to allow the following input:

```
\ch{CH3-CH2-O-}
```

which gives

[image]

And the same happens with an input like

```
\ch{\SIrange[range-phrase= -- ]{10}{20}{\celsius}}
```

`\ch` sees three compounds: `\SIrange[range-phrase=`, `--`, and `]{10}{20}{\celsius}`. You probably see now why this leads to errors. Even worse here: the numbers are treated as subscripts just like the number in `\ch{H2O}`…

Long story short: **if you don't want something to be parsed as formula you need to tell `chemformula` about it!** It has an escape mechanism for this – `"..."`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\ch{A ->[ "\SIrange[range-phrase=--]{10}{20}{\celsius}" ] B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So what about this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,units}}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  "\sisetup{range-units=single,range-phrase=--}"
  A &->[\SI{200}{\celsius}] C + 3 C ^ \\
  2 D + C &->[\SIrange{200}{300}{\celsius}] 2 E ^ + F
\end{reactions}
  
\end{document}
```

Well it compiles but it doesn't give the desired output. Why? Because `reactions` is `align` underneath and `align` is just a sophisticated kind of `tabular`. All of them have in common that single table cells form a group. And since `\sisetup` assignments are local they are forgotten after the next `&` or `\\`.

The simplest solution in your case is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,units}}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  A &->[ "\SI{200}{\celsius}" ] C + 3 C ^ \\
  2 D + C
    &->[ "\SIrange[range-units=single,range-phrase=--]{200}{300}{\celsius}" ]
    2 E ^ + F
\end{reactions}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. And the hint to the solution.

Comment: @Henning you're welcome

Comment: Thanks as well for improving the question.

Comment: Something is still strange:in a `reactions`-environment another similar `\SIrange`- Command :`A + B &->[ "\SIrange[range-units=single,range-phrase={~--~}]{20}{30}{\celsius}" ] C + D` causes 
Errors:"`Package siunitx Error: Unknown option 'range\chemformula_single_bond:(siunitx) units\chemformula_double_bond: single'. \end`" and "`Package siunitx Error: Unknown option 'range\chemformula_single_bond:`". 
As I  puzzled out, the `{...}` in the `range-phrase` option is the root of the evil. `range-phrase=\ --\ ` is without errors. Outside the environment both versions are o.k.